# Only single row displayed in table

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
foreach ($grabdata as $row) {

      echo "<tr>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['EmployeeName'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['EmployeeID'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['ContactNumber'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['Gender'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['DOB'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['AreaOfExpertise'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['State'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td><input class='editValues' type='button' value='Edit'></td>";

      echo "</tr>";

      echo "</table>";

    }
```

I expected all data in the db to be displayed in a table. Unfortunately only the first result appears in the table and the following appear without the table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the end of table tag in your loop, so you end the table on every run

Comment: Remove the last `echo "</table>";`

Comment: Also could you print out the contents of `$grabdata` and make sure it has more than 1 result in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `</table>`-Tag outside of the foreach loop:

```php
echo "<table>";

foreach ($grabdata as $row) {

  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['EmployeeName'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['EmployeeID'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['ContactNumber'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['Gender'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['DOB'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['AreaOfExpertise'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['State'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td class='editableColumns'>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td><input class='editValues' type='button' value='Edit'></td>";

  echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```